# Simple way to get the current docked area of a QToolbar

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qwidget

I'm working on a Qt project, where I need to get the toolbar positions at run-time. Is there any way to get the current positioning of a `QToolbar` inside a `QMainWindow` ?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answer and I got 75% working. But there is a problem in `QMainWindow::toolBarArea(QToolBar * toolbar)`.

When I dock two toolbars in a single area (i.e. Bottom area), as below.

```
-----------------------------------
| Toolbar 1                       |
-----------------------------------
| Toolbar 2                       |
-----------------------------------
```

Then I save the area obtained from `QMainWindow::toolBarArea`, using QSettings and then load them back, it loads as below.

```
-----------------------------------
| Toolbar 1      | Toolbar 2      |
-----------------------------------
```

Is there any way to stop that as well?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I need to get the position of the toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the scope of `QMainWindow`,  you can call [`QMainWindow::toolBarArea(QToolBar *toolbar)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#toolBarArea) to get the toolbar position.

> Returns the Qt::ToolBarArea for toolbar. If toolbar has not been added
>   to the main window, this function returns Qt::NoToolBarArea.

It returns the `enum`:

```
enum ToolBarArea {
        LeftToolBarArea = 0x1,
        RightToolBarArea = 0x2,
        TopToolBarArea = 0x4,
        BottomToolBarArea = 0x8,

        ToolBarArea_Mask = 0xf,
        AllToolBarAreas = ToolBarArea_Mask,
        NoToolBarArea = 0
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find this in the API. Silly me :)

Comment: One more issue. When there are two toolbars docked into the same area, but as a stack (for example, as two rows in the top area), how can I get that position within an area?

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris More specific please? I am not sure what's the issue about. You can pass the target tool bar to the function and return the area where tool bar is located. Otherwise if you want the accurate coordinate, you can call `QToolBar::geometry` to get it (as `QRect`).

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris Your new problem about how to discern stacked toolbar is a good question, and I would like to suggest you start a new post and use a proper title. Not just because updating the original post to a new one is impertinent in SO (You should really avoid that in the future), but start a new post with proper title would help you draw more attention.